# Script in Unity to simulate object movement of an AR camera? Accelerometer

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, accelerometer

I am working on a project where I need to move an object relative to the movement of the camera. I need it to be similar to an AR camera, as if the object was staying still even if the phone is moving.
Does anyone have any idea?

I can't use the gyroscope, as it has low compatibility with Android devices. I am trying to use the accelerometer, but it is not working because the object moves right/left when turning the phone like in a diagonal position, and not when staying vertical and rotating.

This is the code I am using:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x,0 ,0);
}
```

Comment: can't you just add the desired object as a children? that way it will always say relative to the camera

Comment: No, thing is that I want it to stay still even if the camera is moving. If the camera moves right, I want the object to move left, and stay in the same point in the environment.

Comment: i think i still don't fully understand what you try to achieve. Are you working with ARcore or something? Is your Scene a mix of Virtual and Real content? Or are you fully working in Unity with only Virtual content (simulation like)? If you are working with your mobile phone camera and try to fixate the object on real space there is probably not a lot you can do, beside trying to improve the algorithm that calculates the space for the virtual object.

Comment: I am working with AR, but not AR core because I need a lot of compatibility, and not with Vuforia neither. I need a free library/plugin, which is very difficult to find, a good one where I could use plane tracking and simulate the movement of ARCore or Vuforia. Any idea?

Comment: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZWNXsjIvrE)

Comment: This is a video simulating the movement I have now, but I want the object to move also when the phone rotates left/right but being horizontal.. Difficult to explain

Comment: ok, i understand now, so you don't want to work with the physical environment. makes it easier. sadly, gyroscope will be your only option in this case. Smartphones don't have any other way to track/measure angular velocity. Note that the accelerometer is not capable of tracking this movement.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Not every phone have gyroscope, and I need the more % of compatibility posible. Do you know any library or plugins for AR I could use in Unity instead of Vuforia or ARCore? I tried using ARToolkit, but it is a bit obsolete(?)

Comment: In the end it would not matter, all of these APIs use the gyroscope aswell, but it honestly shouldn't be that much of a problem. Every phone that is able to use AR has a gyroscope anyway. the current IMU that are used for mobile phones at least include it. If you want to develope for tech that is older than 10 years you might have a problem with the performance of unity anyway.

Comment: Okay I'll look for another solution then.. Thanks!